# Flutter: The plugin `razorpay_flutter` doesn't have a main class defined in C:\Users\

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

While I am running `flutter pub get` command which is used to fetch the dependencies listed in the `pubspec.yaml` file of your Flutter project, I'm getting this error:

Got dependencies!
The plugin `razorpay_flutter` doesn't have a main class defined in
C:\Users\WindowsX\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\razorpay_flutter-1.3.5\android\src\main\java\com\razorpay\razorpay_flutter\RazorpayFlutterPlugin.java or
C:\Users\WindowsX\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\razorpay_flutter-1.3.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\razorpay\razorpay_flutter\RazorpayFlutterPlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage:   com.razorpay.razorpay_flutter` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of
locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider using a different
plugin in the meanwhile.

1. Verified the plugin installation: I am sure that I have added the `razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.5` dependency correctly in my `pubspec.yaml` file. Checked the version number and indentation. Then, run `flutter pub get` to fetch the plugin and its dependencies.
2. Checked the import statement: Ensured that I have imported the `razorpay_flutter` package correctly in my Dart file. The import statement should be something like `import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';`. If there is an error in the import statement, it can cause the "main class not defined" error.

Comment: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-flutter/issues/330

Comment: down razorpay version and clean pub.dev razorpay cache for this path C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev

Answer (score 4):

Step 1. Go into this path
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\razorpay_flutter-1.3.5
AND delete this folder "razorpay_flutter-1 3.5"
Step 2. In terminal run command "Flutter clean" and "flutter Pub get"...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with me. I did

1. executed  "flutter pub cache clean" In terminal
2. Changed the razorpay plugin version from 1.3.5 to 1.3.3 in pubspec.yaml.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful only for razorpay_flutter 1.3.5. You may have a different version. Remove the version file you use. Like: if you are using razorpy_flutter 1.3.6 then you have to delete the razorpay_flutter 1.3.6 folder.

Note: The version defined in the pubspec.ymal file is not necessarily the same as the one in use, due to the ^ in 1.3.6, Flutter "pub get" picks up an automatically updated version. If you have no idea which version is being used, delete all folders starting with razorpy_flutter in C:\Users<your resource>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).